# Not getting the proper response from paypal tokenize method

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree

I am working on integrating PayPal credit via braintree.

I am in the PayPal [3.22.2 JS version](https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.22.2/js/paypal.min.js).

As per the documentation the [tokenize payload](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/3.22.2/PayPal.html#~tokenizePayload) which is received as a response to the [tokenize method](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/3.22.2/PayPal.html#tokenize) should have an object **creditFinancingOffered** when the payment is made by the PayPal credit but I am not getting this object even if the payment is made via PayPal credit.

Comment: `This property will only be present when the customer pays with PayPal Credit.` Are you in sandbox? select Credit payment as your sandbox option when paying. Enable Credit option on your paypal sandbox buyer account

Comment: In addition to the questions in the comment above, please include code snippets of your client-side integration.